# Securing an "open" web service used by multiple mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, web-services, mobile, windows-mobile

I am developing a web service that will be used by an app on Android, iPhone and Windows Mobile devices.  The app requires no login.  Is there any way I can secure my web service so that only the app running on the mobile devices can access it?  I want to prevent someone from getting a hold of the web service and exploiting it.

Comment: No, you cannot. Some discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671435/how-to-make-a-secure-login-using-udid-or-device-token/4671678#4671678).

Comment: I suppose you could require a login anyway and store the credentials in your app's code. It's not 100% but at least people won't be accessing the web service without the app unless they gut your app and decompile it.